# Executing Process on a remote Machine c#

Tags: c#, wmi, remoting

i connected over WMI on a remote Machine.

username and password is correctly set.

```
var options = new ConnectionOptions();
servicePath = "\\\\Testserver\\root\\cimv2";
options.EnablePrivileges = true;
options.Username = username;
options.Password = pwd;
serviceScope = new ManagementScope(servicePath, options);
serviceScope.Connect();
```

this is the code sequence i want to run on the remote machine

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "diskpart.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("list volume");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();

// extract information from output
string table = output.Split(new string[] { "DISKPART>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
var rows = table.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 3; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    if (rows[i].Contains("Volume"))
    {
        int index = Int32.Parse(rows[i].Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[3]);
        string label = rows[i].Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[8];
        Console.WriteLine($@"Volume {index} {label}:\");
    }
}
```

if i am going to call the process over wmi like this...

```
object[] theProcessToRun = { "diskpart" };
using (var managementClass = new ManagementClass(serviceScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions()))
{
managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
}
```

i can call the process, but havent the possibilites to hand over the commands i would like to execute in this process...

How to solve this ?

Comment: Your lacking a problem description. I'm sure there are WMI classes for the volume information `list volume` returns, why not go that route instead.

Comment: What does this statement mean?  `but havent the possibilites to hand over the commands i would like to execute in this process...`

Comment: I know, that WMI Classes can give me the Volume Information. I know that. But i need a process call, with commands i have to execute. At the moment i am working with the command "List Volumes", because they are not destroying anything. Later i have to extend the volumes, but first i have to transfer the commands to the commandline of that process.

Comment: For better explanation of the problem description. I want to connect to a remote machine over WMI. Thats what i already have done. After that i want to call the diskpart process, because i have to expand a volume later. Unluckily i cant transfer the commands, that i normally can use in the middle code section in my previous post above. So how can i transfer the commands to the process ?

Comment: use Psexe to Executing Process on a remote Machine c#

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script to be passed in as part of the command line arguments that will contain your command.

Reference: https://www.computerhope.com/diskpart.htm

Also you should redirect your output to a file using cmd as you should get your output directly either.

For script, make sure you use a unc that other machine/user has access to.   For output file, make sure you use a unc that other machine/user can write to and you can read from via the program.

Comment: ok, fine, i can call the function like this object[] theProcessToRun = { "diskpart /select volume f" }; -> So diskpart is using volume f. Bit i need a second command for extending the disk. I cant call it twice, if i invoke the command again, as far as i know i call a new instance of that process, correct ?

Comment: Yes..you'd be calling a second process....unless you use the script method that I mention above

Comment: ok, for that part it is necessary that i have a script file. Hmm.... first i thought i can concetenate the commands, but that wont work. I think i have to do it so